# Finding duplicate balls in a basket?

Tags: code-golf, array, restricted-memory

A basket is full with \$n\$ colored balls. For each color except one, there are at least 2 balls with that color. Find the color which only has one ball. in \$O(n)\$ space complexity.

What if each ball is repeated exactly  twice?

You can consider the input to be an array or a list or any container of colors as strings with a maximum length of 100

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Unless you specify some kind of input and output format (or the flexibility of what you allow) people are going to make vastly different assumptions.

Comment: This question isn't suited for CodeGolf.  You need to specify a winning criteria. Otherwise, try StackOverflow.com if you are needing help.

Comment: Do you want us to find the duplicate balls as the title suggests?

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley Yes thats the whole idea!!

Comment: -1 no input format specified, no output format specified... How you output the repeated ball? Index? Is it one indexed or zero indexed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Python - 17 chars

Solely as an expression:

```
min(B,key=B.count)
```

Full, standalone program with input and output, **34 chars**:

```
B=input()
print min(B,key=B.count)
```

edit: What gnibbler said.

Comment: Python3 would be a little shorter - use `input` instead of `raw_input` and `()` around the `print`. Since the input format isn't specified, why not assign single letter codes to each colour? eg "rrgbb", then you can drop the `split()`. And use `min` instead of `sorted` FTW

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I guess a string is within the bounds of 'any container' :D The question doesn't even mention input, so I think it's legit with 2.x's input() and have the user wrap quotes around it too.

Answer (score 6):

## K, <strike>17</strike> 15

```
&1=#:'=" "\:0:0
```

Takes input from stdin as a space separated list

```
k)&1=#:'=" "\:0:0
red red green blue blue
"green"
```

Comment: I think you've got me beat this time - it takes me 15 characters just to get the separate strings.

Comment: ...or maybe not - I've got the input down to 8 which at least gives me a fighting chance... :-)

Comment: Given the way you successively golfed the last one I wouldn't be surprised to see you beat me again. My solution can't get any shorter, I think.

Comment: No, I think 20 is my limit here.

Comment: No need to wrap this in a function, `&1=#:'=" "\:0:0` runs fine for 15.

Answer (score 5):

### J, <strike>31</strike> <strike>24</strike> 20 characters

```
{.(~./:#/.~);:1!:1[1
```

A lot prettier than the previous attempt. Takes input from keyboard.

Makes an assumption that wasn't necessary in the previous version - that there is exactly one colour with one ball. If there are 2 colours with one ball you'll get the first that appears in the list, if there are no colours with only one ball you'll get the colour with the least balls.

Example:

```
   {.(~./:#/.~);:1!:1[1
green green red blue blue
┌───┐
│red│
└───┘
```

Answer (score 3):

## SQL - 44

#### Find Unique Color

```
SELECT C FROM B GROUP BY C HAVING COUNT(C)=1
```

#### Find Duplicate Colors

```
SELECT C FROM B GROUP BY C HAVING COUNT(C)>1
```

Comment: The right tool for the job!

Answer (score 2):

#### Python 2.7, 44 chars

Using the same sort of format as Keith Randall's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6584/62) of a function that takes an array and returns the element/colour that only occurs once.

```
R=lambda B:[a for a in B if B.count(a)<2][0]
```

Alternatively, if I need to read in colours  from the command line and output the colour that is unique (which takes 60 chars):

```
B=raw_input().split();print[a for a in B if B.count(a)<2][0]
```

Comment: This is O(1) space complexity - which is usually better than O(n), but technically isn't what the question asks for :)

Comment: I think you could use `<2` rather than `==1` to save a char.

Comment: @gnibbler: `O(1)` is a subset of `O(n)`.

Comment: @grc: Thanks, amended the solution.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure - 44

```
#(some(fn[[c n]](if(= n 1)c))(frequencies%))
```

That's a lambda function. Example:

```
(#(some(fn[[c n]](if(= n 1)c))(frequencies%))
  [:red :red :red :blue :green :blue :yellow :yellow])
=> :green
```

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 23

After a tremendous amount of help from [w0lf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3527/w0lf), here's the source code.

```golfscript
' '/:x.&{x{1$=},,1=\;},
```

**[DEMO](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydibHVlIGJsdWUgeWVsbG93JwonICcvOnguJnt4ezEkPX0sLDE9XDt9LA%3D%3D)**

---

### 28 characters with the error checking

`?` is displayed if there is not one unique color.  For the sake of keeping the number of characters down to a minimum, the question mark was used (this of course can be changed to something more meaningful).

```golfscript
' '/:x.&{x{1$=},,1=\;},'?'or
```

**[DEMO](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydibHVlIGJsdWUgeWVsbG93IHllbGxvdycKJyAnLzp4LiZ7eHsxJD19LCwxPVw7fSwnPydvcg%3D%3D)**

---

#### Commentary

```golfscript
' '/:x        # split up each element and assign it to 'x'
.&            # copy the last element in the stack and do a "setwise and"
{x            # start filtration process and invoke 'x'
{1$=}         # checks for an equality comparison
,,            # find the count of each unique character
1=            # compare value to '1'
\;            # leave only value that has count of '1' on the stack
},            # close filtration process and print element on stack
'?'or         # OPTIONAL: is printed if no element with a count of '1' is found
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 23

`n` contains the list.

```
Cases[Tally@n,{x_,1}:>x]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
.m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fL/f//2il9KLU1DwlHQUEoyg1BUQl5ZSmwulYAA)

.m is a builtin function which return the least frequent element in a list.

If you are not allowed to use a builtin to solve the challenge, then
it's <s>4</s> 2 bytes:

-2 thanks to @caird coinheringaahing

```
ʒ¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KRDi/7/j1ZKL0pNzVPSUUAwilJTQFRSTmkqnI4FAA)

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KRDi/7/j1ZKL0pNzVPSUUAwilJTQFRSTmkqnI4FAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 67 chars

```
from collections import*
R=lambda B:Counter(B).most_common()[-1][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## R - 18 chars

```
which(table(x)==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL (14)

```
B/⍨1=+/B∘.≡B←⎕
```

Takes input from the keyboard in the form of an APL list, so you need to put quotes around the colors `'like' 'this'`. (Or use numbers.)

```
      B/⍨1=+/B∘.≡B←⎕
⎕:
      'green' 'green' 'red' 'blue' 'blue'
 red
```

As a function (that takes a list, also 14 characters):

```
{⍵/⍨1=+/⍵∘.≡⍵}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 22 chars

```
it.min{a->it.count(a)}
```

Attribution and test case:

```
lone={it.min{a->it.count(a)}}

l = ['red','green', 'red', 'blue', 'green']

assert lone(l) == 'blue'
assert lone(l) != 'red'
```

Comment: You might want to put a link to TIO, like [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/Jz8v1bY6s0QvNzOvOlHXDshKzi/NK9FI1Kyt5eLKUbBViFYvSk1R11FPL0pNzVPXUYBwFdSTckpTQTREPJaLK7G4OLWoRAFkpEaOpoKtLVQNuoSiLcQMroKizDy48P//AA "Groovy – Try It Online")

Comment: @CommandMaster Keep in mind that this question and answer were posting 8 years ago, and that the answerer hasn't been on the site since 2018